# Deploying multiple VM's with ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-vm

I'm learning ansible to create Linux VM's on azure and I used this sample playbook in this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/vm-configure?tabs=ansible) to create one VM on azure.  If I want to deploy 10  VM's exactly like this with ansible-playbook how should I do it? Please help. Thanks in advance

Update: I tried it like this but the script fails after creating two public IP addresses.

```yaml
- name: Create Azure VM
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Create resource group to hold VM
    azure_rm_resourcegroup:
      name: TestingResource
      location: eastus
  - name: Create virtual network
    azure_rm_virtualnetwork:
      resource_group: TestingResource
      name: testingvnet
      address_prefixes: "10.0.0.0/16"
  - name: Add subnet
    azure_rm_subnet:
      resource_group: TestingResource
      name: testingsubnet
      address_prefix: "10.0.1.0/24"
      virtual_network: testingvnet
  - name: Create public IP address
    azure_rm_publicipaddress:
      resource_group: TestingResource
      allocation_method: Static
      name: "{{ item }}" #CHANGE HERE
    loop:
       - testingpublicIP2
       - testingpublicIP3  
    register: output_ip_address
  #- name: Dump public IP for VM which will be created
    #debug:
      #msg: "The public IP is {{ output_ip_address.state.ip_address }}."
  - name: Create Network Security Group that allows SSH
    azure_rm_securitygroup:
      resource_group: TestingResource
      name: TestingSecurityGroup
      rules:
        - name: SSH
          protocol: Tcp
          destination_port_range: 22
          access: Allow
          priority: 1001
          direction: Inbound
  - name: Create virtual network interface card
    azure_rm_networkinterface:
      resource_group: TestingResource
      name: "{{ item }}" #CHANGE HERE
      loop:
         - TestingNIC2
         - TestingNIC3
      virtual_network: testingvnet
      subnet: testingsubnet
      public_ip_name: "{{ item }}" #CHANGE HERE
      loop:
        - testingpublicIP2
        - testingpublicIP3
      security_group: TestingSecurityGroup
  - name: Create VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: TestingResource
      name: "{{ item }}" #CHANGE HERE VM NAME
      loop:
        - TestingResource2
        - TestingResource3
      vm_size: Standard_B2s
      admin_username: admin
      admin_password: password@123 
      ssh_password_enabled: true
      network_interfaces: "{{ item }}" #CHANGE HERE
      loop: 
         - TestingNIC2
         - TestingNIC3
      image:
        offer: UbuntuServer
        publisher: Canonical
        sku: '18.04-LTS'
        version: latest
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried already

Comment: You can use [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html), see the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ansible-playbooks/blob/master/vmss_images/01-create-vms.yml)

Comment: Hi @NancyXiong, in the sample git playbook file there are variables like this name: "{{ resource_group }}", so where does the playbook get the name of the resource group? or do i have to replace what's inside these {{}} brackets?

Comment: Hi @toydarian, I included the playbook that i have tried

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @CharlesXu, I switched to terraform as it is easy for me to understand, and I was able to deploy VM's very quickly and easily. thanks

Comment: But you ask the question and I spend time to give you the solution. You can't ignore it because you change to use another tool. It's unpolite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the loops function to create multiple VMs through ansible as you showed in the question, but you'd better use a list variable to loop so that you don't need to write all the elements every time. And the variables also can be used for other things like resource group name, location, and so on that use multiple times in the code. Here is the example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    resource_group: myResourceGroup
    ...
  tasks:
  - name: Create resource group to hold VM
    azure_rm_resourcegroup:
      name: "{{ resource_group }}"
      location: eastus
  ...
```

And the variable for the loop:

```
loop: "{{ var_list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out it's quite easy with terraform to deploy multiple VM's on azure just by changing one variable in the configuration file, Here's the configuration file that i used (https://github.com/RichardPhilipsRoy/terraform-azure-linuxVMs)